# Why cvFindContours() method doesn't detect Contours correctly in javacv?

Tags: java, opencv, javacv

I went through many questions in StackOverflow and able to develop small program to detect squares and rectangles correctly. This is my sample code

```
public static CvSeq findSquares(final IplImage src, CvMemStorage storage) {
    CvSeq squares = new CvContour();
    squares = cvCreateSeq(0, sizeof(CvContour.class), sizeof(CvSeq.class), storage);
    IplImage pyr = null, timg = null, gray = null, tgray;
    timg = cvCloneImage(src);
    CvSize sz = cvSize(src.width(), src.height());
    tgray = cvCreateImage(sz, src.depth(), 1);
    gray = cvCreateImage(sz, src.depth(), 1);
    // cvCvtColor(gray, src, 1);
    pyr = cvCreateImage(cvSize(sz.width() / 2, sz.height() / 2), src.depth(), src.nChannels());
    // down-scale and upscale the image to filter out the noise
    // cvPyrDown(timg, pyr, CV_GAUSSIAN_5x5);
    // cvPyrUp(pyr, timg, CV_GAUSSIAN_5x5);
    // cvSaveImage("ha.jpg",timg);
    CvSeq contours = new CvContour();
    // request closing of the application when the image window is closed
    // show image on window
    // find squares in every color plane of the image
    for (int c = 0; c < 3; c++) {
        IplImage channels[] = { cvCreateImage(sz, 8, 1), cvCreateImage(sz, 8, 1), cvCreateImage(sz, 8, 1) };
        channels[c] = cvCreateImage(sz, 8, 1);
        if (src.nChannels() > 1) {
            cvSplit(timg, channels[0], channels[1], channels[2], null);
        } else {
            tgray = cvCloneImage(timg);
        }
        tgray = channels[c];
        // // try several threshold levels
        for (int l = 0; l < N; l++) {
            // hack: use Canny instead of zero threshold level.
            // Canny helps to catch squares with gradient shading
            if (l == 0) {
                // apply Canny. Take the upper threshold from slider
                // and set the lower to 0 (which forces edges merging)
                cvCanny(tgray, gray, 0, thresh, 5);
                // dilate canny output to remove potential
                // // holes between edge segments
                cvDilate(gray, gray, null, 1);
            } else {
                // apply threshold if l!=0:
                cvThreshold(tgray, gray, (l + 1) * 255 / N, 255,
                        CV_THRESH_BINARY);
            }
            // find contours and store them all as a list
            cvFindContours(gray, storage, contours, sizeof(CvContour.class), CV_RETR_LIST, CV_CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE);
            CvSeq approx;
            // test each contour
            while (contours != null && !contours.isNull()) {
                if (contours.elem_size() > 0) {
                    approx = cvApproxPoly(contours, Loader.sizeof(CvContour.class), storage, CV_POLY_APPROX_DP, cvContourPerimeter(contours) * 0.02, 0);
                    if (approx.total() == 4 && Math.abs(cvContourArea(approx, CV_WHOLE_SEQ, 0)) > 1000 && cvCheckContourConvexity(approx) != 0) {
                        double maxCosine = 0;
                        for (int j = 2; j < 5; j++) {
                            // find the maximum cosine of the angle between
                            // joint edges
                            double cosine = Math.abs(angle(
                                            new CvPoint(cvGetSeqElem(
                                                    approx, j % 4)),
                                            new CvPoint(cvGetSeqElem(
                                                    approx, j - 2)),
                                            new CvPoint(cvGetSeqElem(
                                                    approx, j - 1))));
                            maxCosine = Math.max(maxCosine, cosine);
                        }
                        if (maxCosine < 0.2) {
                            CvRect x = cvBoundingRect(approx, l);
                            if ((x.width() * x.height()) < 50000) {
                                System.out.println("Width : " + x.width()
                                        + " Height : " + x.height());
                                cvSeqPush(squares, approx);
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
                contours = contours.h_next();
            }
            contours = new CvContour();
        }
    }
    return squares;
}
```

I use this image to detect rectangles and squares

[image]

I need to identify the following output

[image]

and

[image]

But when I run the above code, it detects only the following rectangles. But I don't know the reason for that. Please can someone explain the reason for that.

This is the output that I got.

[image]

Please be kind enough to explain the problem in above code and give some suggensions to detect this squares and rectangles.

Comment: I don't immediately see a problem with your code, but it may simply be that one of your criteria is too harsh. For example, you test if the maximum number of segments in the approximation is 4, but are you sure there are never artifacts so there are 5? Without knowing exactly how the opencv approximation works, certain approximation algorithms will generate spurious segments when they are seeded just before a bend. Also, is the area within the contours always greater than 1000, which you test for?

Comment: It helps to print the intermediate steps (For example, after canny, after threshold, etc) of your algorithm to see what is happening, and post them here for help also.

Answer (score 2):

Given a mask image (binary image, like your second figure), cvFindContours() gives you the contours (several list of points).
look at this link: http://dasl.mem.drexel.edu/~noahKuntz/openCVTut7.html